# tree division(algorithm based)

Tags: algorithm

This was a coding problem asked in one company:

> Given a tree with N nodes and weights associated with each node and
>   edges are given(present in the tree).You have to remove one edge such
>   that the difference of sum of weights of two tree created is maximum.

Input:

> first line contains N the no. of nodes 2nd line contains N integrs
>   denoting weights of each node followed by N-1 lines showing the edges
>   present.

Output:

> the max difference of weights of the created tree.

Example:

Input:

first test case:

```
3
8 7 8
10
21
```

output: `7`

2nd test case:

```
9
5 5 4 1 8 8 3 5 2
10
20
31
41 
53 
60
75
81
```

output: `13` (not sure about this output)

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried, and where did it fail?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i am kind of new to hard problems so i didnt get much far...i just tried figuring out logic...n i feel i should be storing all possible tree weights and then find maximum...but not sure exactly how :(

Comment: Can the weights be negative ?

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan : No they are > 0

Answer (score 2):

If the weights cannot be negative, it's obvious that the optimal solution will be to cut off a  single leaf. Assuming the total tree weight as ***S***, we can find it out in ***O(n)*** as follows:

1. *ans* := 0
2. for each vertex *v*, *ans* := *max*( *ans*, *abs* ( *S* - 2 * *weight*[ *v* ] )) // the difference between remaining part and the leaf
3. return *ans*